# array values not working in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have some code that worked perfectly a few hours ago, and for some reason it is nbow totally useless.

I have scoured the web for hours trying to work out why I am getting a Notice: array to string conversion error.

On a previous page I post and array of team names to the page where the error message is created.

If I var_dump the array (which is called $teams) all the data is there, every team name in an array.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(6) "Team a" [1]=> string(6) "Team a" [2]=> string(6) "Team a" [3]=> string(6) "Team b" [4]=> string(6) "Team b" [5]=> string(6) "Team b" [6]=> string(6) "Team c" [7]=> string(6) "Team c" [8]=> string(6) "Team c" [9]=> string(6) "Team d" [10]=> string(6) "Team d" [11]=> string(6) "Team d" } }
```

Note, the team names are repeated as this is a fixture list, so each team plays each team.

However, the array to string conversion error is occuring in my query.

So, at the top of the page I create an array from the data posted like this...

```
$team[]=$_POST['team'];
```

then in my query I run a for loop and run the query, summarised as follows;

```
$count=count($team);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++ {
$query=$database->query("UPDATE pool_a SET ......where team_name='$team[$i]')"
```

I am so confused, I did a bit of editing earlier to try to add further queries to produce tables for pool_b, pool_c etc but I scrapped them and I am sure the code is as it was this morning.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It appears that there is a value inside `$team` that is also an array. Can you edit your answer with the var_dump of `$team`?

Comment: yep just added the var_dump

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `var_dump()` you posted, it looks like you array is actually located at `$team[0]`.

It looks like you need to change this:

```
$team[] = $_POST['team'];
```

to this:

```
$team = $_POST['team'];
```

Assigning to `$team[]` in essence gave you an extra array wrapper around your data.

Since you also have duplicate values in the array, before querying the database you should reduce array only to unique values.

```
$team = array_unique($team);
```

You would be best served using a single query with all your items in it:

```
$query = "UPDATE pool_a SET ... WHERE team_name IN('" . implode("','", $team) . "')";
$database->query($query);
```

Comment: @user2933231 Just edited my answer. It looks like you data is in `$teams[0]`

Comment: doesn't taking away the [] mean it won't be treated as an array?

Comment: i am now getting invalid offset errors for each iteration of that line in the query loop

Comment: @user2933231 If the posted data is already in array format, you just want to assign the post value directly to the array.  Try `var_dump($_POST['team'])` to verify this.  Also, you should not be querying in loop.  Get unique values from array (since there are duplicates) and make single DB query as shown in my answer.

Comment: Vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Comment: @EthanB You are correct in pointing this out. One should escape each value in `$_POST['team']` as well as possible validate that it contains expected data formatting if applicable.  I did not show here as this is tangential to the actual issue asked about.